# How do I return distinct values with options_from_collection_for_select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I am trying to return the countries of my products within a select tag using

```
options_from_collection_for_select()
```

I have a Product model, with country as a column name. My code looks like this

```
<%= select_tag(:country, options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all.order(:country), :id, :country), :prompt => "Alle Länder") %>
```

However it gives me each country more than once in the dropdown field i.e. each country appears 20 times.

Now I've been trying to use a solution suggested in a similar question, like so

```
options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all.pluck('DISTINCT country'), :id, :country), :prompt => "Alle Länder") %>
```

however I get an error stating:

```
"undefined method `country' for "Spain":String
Did you mean?  count"
```

Now I cant figure out which method is appropriate in this case.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You already get strings when you use `pluck`. Also I suppose that query would give you ID's of Products, not countries. Perhaps your model should have a country_id instead of a country name? You can try `select_tag(:country, Product.all.pluck('DISTINCT country'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get non-uniq values because there's more, than one row in db with given country.

```
= f.select :country,
  Product.pluck(:country).uniq,
  { include_blank: 'Select country' }
```

If you want to still use `select_tag`:

```
= select_tag :country,
  options_for_select(Product.pluck(:country).uniq),
  { include_blank: 'Select country' }
```

Comment: i assumed that you have `Country` model because your select fields is called `country_id`

Comment: This could potentially be slow because you're fetching all records from the database and then having ruby handle the deduplication. I think the OP wants to handle this at the DB layer (and rightfully so).

Comment: thank you for the answer, however I dont have a country table :( is it possible only with having a country table?

Comment: @KyleDecot show me please, where exactly am I using Ruby handling duplication? ;)

Comment: @AaronDT then why would you have the field called **`counrty_id`**?

Comment: Well you edited it by the time I finished typing but you were calling uniq on and array.

Comment: @AaronDT yes, but it is a bit weird what you're doing there.. let me edit the answe

Comment: good point, i will change it. I took the naming convention from a tutorial and matched it with my "names". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @KyleDecot calling uniq on an array will never slow down. why? because I call it on Array, not on AR ;)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thank you very much, however I still get the same error :(

Comment: do I replace it with the current select statement or does it go inside the statement?

Comment: @AaronDT replace :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I'm sorry but that just isn't the case. If you run my benchmark (https://gist.github.com/kyledecot/a05982af3ae2d718795e435c0aa2f36e) you'll see that it is not constant